# Sort a List of Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a series of string fields for an object. I want to create multiple in a loop, and then sort them based on one of the fields. Here is what i have so far

```
string[] EventArray = new string[3];
    EventArray[0] = "STRStartDateTime" //Sort by this field A->Z
    EventArray[1] = "StartTimeOut";
    EventArray[2] = "EndTimeOut";
List<Array> EventsUnsorted = new List<Array>();
EventsUnsorted.Add(EventArray);

//Sort Events

foreach (Array Event in EventsSorted)
{
    string Output = Event.GetValue(2).ToString();
}
```

What method should I use for sorting and generally have I taken the right approach for storing data like this?

Comment: Do you want to sort your `List<Array>` or the items in the `string[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two easiest options are:

- `EventsUnsorted.Sort()` - By default, a `List<String>` uses a current culture, case-insensitive ascending sort.
- `EventsUnsorted.OrderBy()` - You'll supply the field(s) to sort by e.g. `.OrderBy(x=>x.EventID)`

Comment: will this let me sort by a specific field of my array?

Comment: Simply, yes, using the `OrderBy`. See updated example. To use a specific field with `Sort()` you'll have to create an `IComparer(T)` and implement your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple Linq expression :

```
var EventsSorted = EventsUnsorted.OrderBy(event => event[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `List<string[]>` and add the itens ordered, for sample:

```
// create the array
string[] EventArray = new string[3];
EventArray[0] = "STRStartDateTime"
EventArray[1] = "StartTimeOut";
EventArray[2] = "EndTimeOut";

// create the list
List<string[]> EventsUnsorted = new List<string[]>();
EventsUnsorted.Add(EventArray);

// sort by 0 index
EventsUnsorted = EventsUnsorted.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToList(); 

foreach (string[] e in EventsSorted)
{
    string Output = e[2].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.Sort method.

```
string[] EventArray = new string[3];
    EventArray[0] = "STRStartDateTime" //Sort by this field A->Z
    EventArray[1] = "StartTimeOut";
    EventArray[2] = "EndTimeOut";
Array.Sort(EventArray);
```